# Is it possible to prevent an user to write on removable drives?

Tags: permissions, security, usb-drive, user-management, storage

Say I want to restrict the users of a PC from writing data to removable drives (USB drives, SD cards, possibly CD/DVD) on Ubuntu 17.04, to prevent (to some extent) data leaks.

This is possible on Windows by editing the registry, is it also possible on Ubuntu? I'm open to any method from account rights to only using a guest user, to lower level config. Only an admin should be able to circumvent the restriction, either by disabling it or by having different access rights (preferrable).

I've read around that this is a very weak protection, but I'm requested to do it and would just know if there is a way to do it. Plus, I think that it can prevent some 'accidental' or light-minded leaks.